# Object required:'WshShell'

Tags: vbscript

Hey Everyone I'm trying to make a simple VBS script and I keep getting Error bject required:'WshShell'

Here is the script

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\DEXIS\DEXsync.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()
```

I have also attached the error message. can someone please help I feel like i'm taking crazy pills
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO1B1.png)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set that WshShell variable you are using to a new Wscript.Shell object. Try something like this instead:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\DEXIS\DEXsync.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()
```